# Including Library Projects in Project Android

Tags: android, library-project

Is there a way to include a library project in a project without it being a separate project?  The ideal situation is to be able to make code changes to the library project and push it to the git repo with the main referencing project.

Answer (score 0):

You can add libraries to your build path.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the library project as a jar file and then you can add that jar file in your `libs` folder and configure your build path to add it to your project.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible as stated here: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjectsIt states in the 4th paragraph down (not including note and bullets), "However, a library project differs from an standard Android application project in that you cannot compile it directly to its own .apk and run it on an Android device. Similarly, you cannot export the library project to a self-contained JAR file, as you would do for a true library. Instead, you must compile the library indirectly..."